# Why does query return a line when using a date filter when it shouldn't?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a query that's trying to filter information based on a date, but it's not quite working.

Using this query:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.ondate, 111)
from WS_ACTIVITY r
```

I get this result:

```
------------------------------
2017/03/16
```

But when running this query:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM [dbo].[WS_ACTIVITY] r
WHERE r.request_type = 2 OR r.request_type = 7 OR r.request_type = 51  AND 
(CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.ondate, 111) 
BETWEEN '2017/10/18' AND '2017/10/18') ORDER BY r.user_id
```

I get the following result:

```
id          egn_bul              request_xml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      response_xml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     user_id     user_name                                                                                            user_department_id user_department_name                                                                                 request_id  request_type is_from_cashe ondate                  ondate_response
----------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------ ------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
7           8903304365                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL        NULL                                                                                                 NULL               NULL                                                                                                 NULL        7            1             2017-03-16 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

when I shouldn't, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
(r.request_type = 2 OR r.request_type = 7 OR r.request_type = 51) 
 AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.ondate, 111) BETWEEN '2017/10/18' AND '2017/10/18')
```

so it's like both clauses should be true to return the result.This has to do with [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql)

Comment: There's an additional "and" in there, but this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM [dbo].[WS_ACTIVITY] r
WHERE (r.request_type = 2 OR r.request_type = 7 OR r.request_type = 51 ) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.ondate, 111) BETWEEN '2017/10/18' AND '2017/10/18') ORDER BY r.user_id
```

In the code posted condition `r.request_type = 7` is TRUE so there is no difference what your data is because your conditions have `OR` between them